# firestore rules to compare the inpudata and already existing data

Tags: angularjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

how to write the firestore rules to compare the data inside th document with in incoming data

actually i want to insert or write the new document to the firestore collection only if the start date and hall number of new data is not equal to start date and hall number of already existing data.

The structure of my db is shown in the following image

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to adjust the structure of your documents. Set custom ids on your documents to be something similar to {date}_{hall} (i.e. 2018-05-04_1). The downside to this is you will need a firestore trigger to watch for create events, and updates if you want, to make sure the ids are in the correct format. Due to the constraints within the Firestore security rules, I believe this is the only way to achieve what you're asking.

```
service cloud.firestore {
    match /databases/{database}/documents {

        match /events/{eventId} {
            allow read: if true;
            allow create: if !exists(get(/databases/$(database)/documents/events/$(eventId));
            allow update: if false; // Depends if you want to be able to update documents
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out the firestore secuirty rules [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/security/).

```
alow read, write: if request.resource.data.propertyName == resource.data.propertyName
```

Comment: this are my firestore rules but still it is not working `service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read: if true;      
      allow write: if (request.resource.data.start != resource.data.start);
    }
  }
}`

Comment: Please see my other answer